# Read a file and count how many times the vowels (characters) "aeiou" appear in order

Tags: java

It ignores consonants.
It ignores any type of space.
It ignores case.
The only thing it cannot ignore is if another vowel occurs out of order.

These count:

```
AEIOU,
aeiou,
hahehihohu,
Take it out
```

These do not:

```
AEIuO,
Taco is good,
Take it over
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AEIOU_Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("vowels.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    String fileContent = "";
    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        fileContent += input.next() + " ";
    }
    input.close();

    char[] charArr = fileContent.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;
    for (char c : charArr)
    {
        if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' ||c == 'i' ||c == 'o' ||c == 'u')
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("The file " + file + " has AEIOU in order " + counter + " times");
}
}
```

The problem is the output:
The file vowels.txt has AEIOU in order 50 times

However, the file vowels.txt contains:

```
AEIOU aeiou baeiboeu bbbaaaaaa beaeiou caeuoi ajejijoju aeioo 
aeiOu ma me mi mo mu take it OUT!
```

So the correct output should be:

`The file vowels.txt has AEIOU in order 8 times`

Comment: You're counting the number of vowels, but you should instead be checking the number of times AEIOU appears in order. A good way to start would be to first check for A, and if the next vowel is not E, reset and check for A again, and so on and so forth.

Comment: you code counts vowels. You didn't even attempt to verify their order.

Comment: This code is incrementing the counter every time it sees a vowel.  If any given character is a, e, i, o, or u you increment the counter.  What you're more interested in is if each character is the right vowel.

Comment: Look into using a regular expression. (Are you sure its 8 times and not 7?)

Comment: See thats the thing guys, I'm not sure how to go about verifying the order. Should I create an arrary and then for loop? My professor recommended nested loops yet I'm not sure how to do it. I'm relatively knew to coding.

Comment: what about AEEIOU? does that count as none/one/two ?

Comment: Do you want the answer to your hw problem or help to point you in the right direction?

Comment: Jimmy, please upvote the answers that helped you and accept the answer that you chose. Its how you show gratitude to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

theres two ways i can think to do it. No real code since this is your assignment :)

first way is to edit the input to be as simple as possible.

```
1. Read input from file
2. toLowerCase() the input (to make "aEiOU" simplar as just "aeiou")
3. Remove all non-vowel characters. (so that 'hahehihohu' becomes 'aeiou')
4. Search for literal string "aeiou" and count occurrances.
```

Second way is leave the input alone, but use loops and counters. the 'sequence' could be an array, or a linked list maybe

```
sequence = [a,e,i,o,u] // (or a->e->i->o->u)
curr_char_of_sequence = 'a'
counter = 0

for each char in the input, loop {
    if the char is not a vowel {
        continue to next char
    }

    //see if the vowel is the one we want next
    if char == curr_char_of_sequence {
        //it is! update whats the next vowel we want.
        // ie, if we were looking for an 'a', now look for an 'e'
        curr_char_of_sequence = sequence.next 

        //check to see if we reached the end of the sequence, if so, we found a completed 'aeiou' set
        if curr_char_of_sequence == invalid {
           counter++
           curr_char_of_sequence = 'a'
       }

    //we found a vowel that isn't the right one, restart the sequence
    } else {
        curr_char_of_sequence = 'a'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As people pointed out, you should use regular expression.
Here is a little help to get you every AEIOU in this specific order (doesn't ignore the non vowels in between)

```
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("vowels.txt");

        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String fileContent = "";
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            fileContent += input.next().toLowerCase();
        }
        input.close();


        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<fileContent.length()-4;i++)
        {
            if(fileContent.charAt(i) == 'a'){
                if(fileContent.charAt(i+1)=='e'){
                    if(fileContent.charAt(i+2)=='i')
                        if(fileContent.charAt(i+3)=='o')
                            if(fileContent.charAt(i+4)=='u'){
                                counter++;
                            }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The file " + file + " has AEIOU in order " + counter + " times");
    }
```

Comment: You need to worry about OutOfBoundsException with this. Maybe update the loop to `i < fileContent.length() - 4`

Comment: Wait, this won't work... That's only if the vowels are contiguous, but I believe OP's question is in the event the vowels aren't contiguous.

Comment: Seems like op didn't know how to start at all, thats why I said it won't work for his specific question - wanted to give him a hint. As for cricket, you are absolutely right, thanks, will edit.

Comment: @Ron Ahh. I missed that line. I was reading the code and relating it to the question. On a related note, this code doesn't count for upper-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it counts every times theres ONE of these letters. (a OR e OR i...)

Try using booleans, if u have a letter ("a"), u look for the next ("e").

```
for (char c : charArr)
{
    if(c == 'a') {
        boolA = true;
    }
    else if(c=='e') {
        if (boolA) {
            boolE = true;
        }
        else {
            boolA = false;
            boolE = false;
            boolI = false;
            boolO = false;
            boolU = false; 
        }
    }
    else if (c=='i') {
        if (boolE) {
            boolI = true;
        }
        else {
            boolA = false;
            boolE = false;
            boolI = false;
            boolO = false;
            boolU = false;  
    }
    //etc, etc ....
}
```

if u understand what i mean ^^

Or, there is the other way (for the lazy dudes)
u remember the last valide character u found, and if the actual letters follows it, it's won.

```
char lastChar;
String validLetters = "aeiou";
String myArray = "eiou"; //i removed the first

for (char c : charArr) {
    if (c=='a') {
        lastChar=='a';
    }
    else if ( validLetters.contains(c) && lastChar==validLetters.charAt(myArray.indexOf(c)) ) {
        lastChar = c; //u understand it, u get the answer ^^
    }
    else {
        lastChar='w' //just a random char, not in AEIOU
}
```

the last one is better,
Hope it helps, Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Me Good Guy beat me to it, but here is a full example with the boolean idea

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean a = false;
    boolean e = false;
    boolean i = false;
    boolean o = false;
    boolean u = false;

    int vowelCounter = 0;

    String s = "AEIOU aeiou hahehihohu Take it out";

    for (int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++) {
        Character c = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(index));
        if (c == 'a') {
            a = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (a && c == 'e') {
            e = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (a && e && c == 'i') {
            i = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (a && e && i && c == 'o') {
            o = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (a && e && i && o && c == 'u') {
            u = true;
            // no continue because we want to exit this if-chain
        }

        if (a && e && i && o && u) {
            vowelCounter++;
            a = e = i = o = u = false; // reset
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("The string \"%s\" contains 'aeiou' in order %d times.\n", s, vowelCounter);
    // The string "AEIOU aeiou hahehihohu Take it out" contains 'aeiou' in order 4 times.
}
```